# jQuery resize all images on document ready by class

Tags: php, jquery, image, resize

I have a page with images which I want them all to be resized (by acquiring certain CSS classes) on document ready using jQuery. The images have an initial ".test" which has no attributes in the CSS file. I know how to give them the new classes so they can be resized. But, I want to resize depending on width or height so they can all look the same.

My problem is that I cannot get their width/height to proceed. My code is this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.test').each(function(){
        var img_width = $(this).width();
        var img_height = $(this).height();
        alert("My width:" + img_width + "px, My Height: " + img_height + "px");

        if (img_width > img_height)
        {
            //resize to height
        }else{
            //resize to width
        }
    });
})
```

The alert I have before the if statement always returns 0 - although it does appear the correct number of times.

I also tried getting the width (and also the height) with `$(this).width;` and `$(this).offsetHeight;` and `$(this).attr('width');` but when the result is not 0, it's `undefined`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It does work, I created a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tLmPX/ to test it. Unless the element with class name test are not img tags, It should work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
$(window).load(function() {
```

instead of

```
$(document).ready(function(){
```

The load event is triggered a bit later when all the images have actually loaded.

> use jQuery's .load() method to attach load event handlers to the
>   window or to more specific items, like images.

Source: http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: This is correct! Thank you very much! But I have one question. When I tried having it `$(window).load(function(){ $('.test').each(function(){ ... etc` it works great. I gave it a try on `$(document).ready(function(){ $('.test').load(function(){ ...` and it works only for some of the images. Do you know why that occurs?

Comment: @Jonur: Have a look at http://api.jquery.com/load-event/ and look for "Caveats of the load event when used with images". Here you'll see a list of drawbacks with load. It's possible that some of your images are in the cache.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.test').load(function(){
        var img_width = $(this).width();
        var img_height = $(this).height();
        alert("My width:" + img_width + "px, My Height: " + img_height + "px");

        if (img_width > img_height)
        {
            //resize to height
        }else{
            //resize to width
        }
    });
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also check out SLIR: https://github.com/lencioni/SLIR

Answer (score 0):

I ran across this problem a while ago too. The problem is that the images are not fully loaded yet.

However, I would suggest NOT to do it this way. Loading a big picture, then resize it clientside is not a good method. You should consider resizing it serverside so users don't have to download large images for no use.

You should take a look at phpThumb, which is a great PHP-class that resizes and caches the images for you. It's a great tool and a much better way to achieve this.